# why doesn't kdialog send notification properly?

Tags: bash, kde, notification

Here is the command:

```
kdialog --passivepopup 'This is a notification' 55
```

This command sends a notification at the up-right corner of the screen, with a blue background and white text.

[image]

I am expecting something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed any other desktop environments lately?

Comment: I have xfce and i3wm.

Comment: What is the output if `dpkg -l | grep noti`?

Comment: So, here an answer that's work for me

http://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 1):

Using @Seth 's suggestion, I figured out it's because I installed dunst, a dmenu-ish notification daemon.

```
dpkg -l | grep noti
ii  dunst                                          1.0.0-2                                       amd64        dmenu-ish notification-daemon
ii  dzen2                                          0.9.5~svn271-3                                amd64        General-purpose messaging and notification program for X11
ii  freespacenotifier                              4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1                           amd64        free space notification module for KDE
ii  gir1.2-notify-0.7                              0.7.6-1ubuntu1                                amd64        sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon (Introspection files)
ii  inotify-tools                                  3.14-1                                        amd64        command-line programs providing a simple interface to inotify
ii  kubuntu-notification-helper                    13.10ubuntu1                                  amd64        Kubuntu system notification helper
ii  libevent-2.0-5:amd64                           2.0.21-stable-1                               amd64        Asynchronous event notification library
ii  libgtk2-notify-perl                            0.05-3build1                                  amd64        Perl interface to libnotify
ii  libinotifytools0                               3.14-1                                        amd64        utility wrapper around inotify
ii  libknotifyconfig4                              4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1                           amd64        library for configuring KDE Notifications
ii  libnotify-bin                                  0.7.6-1ubuntu1                                amd64        sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon (Utilities)
ii  libnotify4:amd64                               0.7.6-1ubuntu1                                amd64        sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon
ii  libstartup-notification0:amd64                 0.12-3                                        amd64        library for program launch feedback (shared library)
ii  libstartup-notification0-dev:amd64             0.12-3                                        amd64        library for program launch feedback (development headers)
ii  libzephyr4:amd64                               3.1~beta0-1                                   amd64        Project Athena's notification service - non-Kerberos libraries
ii  muon-notifier                                  2.1.3-0ubuntu0.2                              amd64        update notifier for KDE
ii  pidgin-libnotify                               0.14-9ubuntu2                                 amd64        display notification bubbles in pidgin
ii  python-notify                                  0.1.1-3ubuntu1                                amd64        Python bindings for libnotify
ii  python-pyinotify                               0.9.3-2                                       all          simple Linux inotify Python bindings
ii  update-notifier                                0.147.1                                       amd64        Daemon which notifies about package updates
ii  update-notifier-common                         0.147.1                                       all          Files shared between update-notifier and other packages
ii  vlc-plugin-notify                              2.0.8-1                                       amd64        LibNotify plugin for VLC
ii  xfce4-notifyd                                  0.2.4-2                                       amd64        simple, visually-appealing notification daemon for Xfce
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Dunst gets installed when you install i3.