# Problem Notify Popup only display blue bar On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, notification

I have Ubuntu 14.04, but not from clean install. I update it from 13.04 -> 13.10 and 14.04. 
Some day ago, I just realize that some things wrong with it's Notification Pop Up. It only display blue bar at top left screen.

I already reset my unity, but nothing happen.
Please help, whats is wrong and how to fix this.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notify-osd notifications appear unthemed in top-left corner](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner)

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

I thinks it's duplicate with : [Notify-osd notifications appear unthemed in top-left corner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner-ubuntu-13-10)

I remember that this problem began when I install `i3` window manager. Unfortunately `i3` automatic install it's own notification daemon, dunst that "conflic" with `notify-osd`. So, I just have to uninstall `i3` and all fixed.

```
sudo apt-get purge i3 i3-wm i3lock i3status dunst
sudo apt-get autoremove
killall dunst
```

Comment: Removing i3 to fix notification looks is almost as useful advice as installing Windows instead of Ubuntu if wifi driver does not work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a package is missing.  Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, which should install any missing packages.  If that doesn't fix it, maybe you disabled something in a config file or an autostart .desktop file.

Comment: I already done that, but still nothing change.

Comment: After doing it, log out and back in.  Also, I have no idea what "I already reset my unity" means.

Comment: I installed gnome-shell and notification working. T Think it's Unity's problem

Comment: I already logout, restart and shutdown. Nothing change.

Comment: Ok, try `sudo aptitude purge ~nunity` and then install `ubuntu-desktop` again.  If that doesn't help, try deleting any unity config files in your homedir (probably in `~/.config/unity` or something like that).

Comment: ~nunity ? sudo aptitude purge unity ?

Comment: `~nunity` marks all packages with "unity" in the name (run `man aptitude` and press `/~` and then press Enter).  `unity` is probably a metapackage, so purging it would do nothing.  Just run the command I gave you.  :)

Comment: OK, I will try that.

Comment: I already uninstall ubuntu-desktop unity notify-osd, and reinstall it, but still not luck. It's already frustrate me.

Comment: Ok, make a new user account, log in as that user, and test it again.  If it works, you'll know there's some configuration file that's causing the problem.

Comment: still no luck. I create new user, try guest user and all just the same.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to remove the dunst notification daemon

```
sudo apt-get remove dunst
```