# awesome overwrote xfce notifications

Tags: xfce, notification, awesome

I installed awesome and i3 to try out fully tiled window managers, and it looks like the styling from awesome's notifications has overtaken xfce4's. Neither `notify-osd` nor `notification-daemon` are installed, and no changes the the Notifications xfce settings take effect. Purging awesome did not help either.

Example screenshot (notification stuck in upper left):

[image: Imgur]

How do I get back to xfce notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me and this helped:

[Notify-osd notifications appear unthemed in top-left corner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner/383930#383930)

i3 installs dunst, which takes over ubuntu's notification system and shows notifications with i3 styling.

Stopping and uninstalling dunst fixed the problem for me.