# notify-osd replaced with dunst after switching back to unity from i3wm

Tags: unity, notification, notify-osd

I was testing i3wm (`sudo apt-get install i3` is what I ran, and chose i3 from the log in screen) on my machine and after a while, decided to switch back to Unity. Upon switching back, I noticed that notifications came in the top right corner similar to i3 even though I was using Unity.

I'd really like it to use the normal Unity notification bubbles instead.

I looked into it and turns out instead of `notify-osd`, `dunst` is being used.

I tried using `sudo vim /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` and editing the file, but it has the correct line (i.e. `Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd`) as expected.

I also tried `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` but that didn't do anything.

Is it possible for me to return to the normal notifications? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Edit: I was able to return to the normal notifications by removing i3wm itself (and dunst). What I am actually asking is: is it possible to change to normal notifications while still keeping i3 and dunst on my system?

Note: This is NOT a duplicate of [Notify-osd notifications appear unthemed in top-left corner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner). The solution there is to remove dunst and I would like to keep dunst and have that work when I choose i3, and have notify-osd work when I choose Unity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I realize I'm two years late to the party, but if anyone else encounters this problem, here's a solution that will use notify-osd when logged into Unity, and dunst when running i3.

If you just want to keep dunst installed, but not auto-invoke it via DBus skip to the Quick Hack section.

## Dunst in i3, notify-osd in Unity

### Step 1

We want to override the behaviors of `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` and more importantly `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.knopwob.dunst.service`.

Since Dbus looks at $XDG_DATA_HOME when searching for service files, and Ubuntu for some reason doesn't set that environment variable, we need to do it ourselves:

```
echo 'export XDG_DATA_HOME=${XDG_DATA_HOME:="$HOME/.local/share"}' >> ~/.profile
```

### Step 2

We need to create our service file:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/dbus-1/services
nano $HOME/.local/share/dbus-1/services/usernotify.service
```

Make the file look like this:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/bin/my_notifier
```

### Step 3

Create the script referred to in your D-BUS file that invokes dunst if i3 is running, otherwise notify-osd:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/my_notifier
```

Make it look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
if pgrep -x i3 >/dev/null; then
    /usr/bin/dunst
else
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
fi
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/my_notifier
```

### Step 4

That should be it. Log out and then log in again. Test it in both Unity and i3 by running

```
notify-send foo bar
```

## Quick Hack

If you exclusively want to use notify-osd it's enough to edit `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.knopwob.dunst.service` accordingly:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
#Exec=/usr/bin/dunst
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
```

Comment: Even at 2 years late, this answer is super helpful :) I have marked it as accepted, since reading the steps, it makes complete sense as to why this should work. Thanks! :) I unfortunately do _not_ switch b/w Unity and i3 anymore, and instead use Gnome and Stumpwm; but still this answer was extremely helpful for learning! :)

Comment: It is not needed to set `XDG_DATA_HOME` as the directory `"$HOME/.local/share"` is used by default, see [the spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). It would be better to create the service file in `/use/local/share/dbus-1/services/` to affect all users. Still I see something about `dunst` in `journalctl -b0` output, so I wonder, if there is better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge dunst
```

That should remove it.

Comment: Please read the note at the bottom of the question. `I would like to keep dunst and have that work when I choose i3, and have notify-osd work when I choose Unity.`