# After Installing Unity I get Unity Style Notifications in KDE?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, notification

I just installed the Ubuntu desktop environment (Unity), and now I'm getting Ubuntu style notifications in KDE. I don't really like this in Plasma, so how can I revert to the Kubuntu style notifications without uninstalling Unity?

Edit 0: This might have something to do with me switching my layout to lightdm, but I'm not certain.

[image: Ubuntu Style Notifications]

Comment: In my opinion, it's not the best thing to have both Unity and KDE together as you're seeing. Unity uses `notify-osd`. And because you installed Unity afterwards, `notify-osd` has taken over. I would just leave things as they are and when you next install a distro, make sure you install **only** the desktop environment you prefer and no other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have multiple notification services installed simultaneously.

Unfortunately, [dbus doesn't seem to be able to intelligently select the appropriate notification service](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=484945), so you will either need to disable one of the services (as detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092324/18380)), or, if you want to keep both `notify-osd` and KDE's Plasma notification service installed and enabled, you will probably need to resort to a [cumbersome workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/957624/18380).

N.B: If you opt for the workaround you will need to adapt the shell script in Step 3 to

1. detect when either KDE or Unity is running
2. run `/usr/bin/plasma_waitforname org.freedesktop.Notifications` when KDE is running