# How do I disable Dunst and go back to notify-osd?

Tags: notification, dbus

I installed `i3`, which recommends `dunst`, but I'm not using i3 at the moment, and the dunst notifications don't really fit with Unity. I'd rather not uninstall dunst totally, since I might want to start using it at some point in the future; is there a way to switch back to notify-osd without uninstalling dunst?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The notification daemon is started by dbus-daemon when a notification is sent. You can see the currently-active notification daemon (assuming there is one) by searching for the `org.freedesktop.Notifications` bus name on the session bus in D-Feet; you can also examine `journalctl` output to see what dbus-daemon thinks it's doing, and why (including e.g. which application sent a notification).

dbus-daemon looks at the service files in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/` to find the service to run for each bus name. The file `org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` is the file for notify-osd (on default Ubuntu 18.04), and dunst installs a new service at `org.knopwob.dunst.service`. Both files have a `Name` of `org.freedesktop.Notifications`, meaning that they're both capable of handling notifications.

Unfortunately, dbus-daemon isn't very clever when it comes to working out which service to start when there are multiple possible services for a given bus name. As of 2018, it [just picks the first one it finds](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/bus/activation.c#n466); there's been a [feature request](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=484945) in Red Hat Bugzilla about this for almost a decade. The only real solutions appear to be:

- write your own service that picks whether to start notify-osd or dunst based on some factor (covered in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/957624/478436)), or
- move or delete all but one of the conflicting service files.

Moving the conflicting service files is much easier in this case: just run `sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.knopwob.dunst.service{,.disabled}`. If you want to start using dunst again, it's easy enough to rename the file back to what it was originally.

Comment: I upvoted this almost a year and a half ago.  Since then my package manager replaced the file I'd moved out of the way and I forgot how I disabled dunst, and I spent half an hour scouring the internet until I ran across this post again.  I wish I could upvote twice.