# How do I reset Notification style to default in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, themes, notification, notification-area

Recently my notification style got changed while trying out different theme, icon and i3wm (which I removed later), but I'm not able to reset it to default.

Notification Image:

[image: Notification Image]

And to make things worse this notification style don't have support to respond to any event for example: No confirm button to confirm the pass-code to connect to Bluetooth.

Bluetooth Error notification:

[image: Bluetooth Error notification]

System:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
- Shell: zsh 5.4.2
- DE: Xfce
- WM: Xfwm4
- WM Theme: ABCD-blue
- GTK Theme: ABCD-blue [GTK2]
- Icon Theme: Tela-circle
- Font: Sans 10

Comment: Please add more information via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1250658/edit) to your question. Ubuntu version? Used theme? `while trying out some stuff`, which stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to i3wm. I guess dunst notification daemon override the default one. You may refer to some other helpful solutions:

[how-do-i-disable-dunst-and-go-back-to-notify-osd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092323/how-do-i-disable-dunst-and-go-back-to-notify-osd)

[notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner?rq=1)