# How to change notification daemon

Tags: kde, notification

So I want to switch my notification daemon from KDE Plasma's default to Dunst.

I couldn't find any working way to do so, and anything I got to know when doing all the things written in articles and other questions is that my `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` file doesn't exist, as seen on screenshot.

Screenshot from terminal, o.f.N with o.f.A.C for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJLbv.png (I can't post images)

Answer (score 0):

On my system `org.freedesktop.Notifications` is the name of a D-BUS service invoked by the file `org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service`.

This is the content of `org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service`:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/bin/plasma_waitforname org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

This is the content of `org.knopwob.dunst.service`:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/bin/dunst
SystemdService=dunst.service
```

Although it's the opposite of what you are trying to do, the accepted answer to the question [How do I disable Dunst and go back to notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1092324/247862) may be of interest. It discusses how which `org.freedesktop.Notifications` service is chosen and it looks like there is some room for improvement in the process.