# New mail notification changed to a blue string in the upper left corner

Tags: unity, thunderbird, notification, notify-osd, notify-send

[image]After recent update my new mail notification is changed to a very simple blue line in the upper left corner of the screen. Any ideas how can I change it back to a normal Unity notification? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity.

Comment: To get notifications you actually need an addon to do so, have you check what addons you have?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, all my addons that I used to have when it was working are enabled.

Comment: This clearly is a notify-osd issue, since notify-send displays all the notifications in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to this:
[Notify-osd notifications appear unthemed in top-left corner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371020/notify-osd-notifications-appear-unthemed-in-top-left-corner?rq=1)

It turned out that the problem appeared after I played around with the `i3` windows manager. I didn't like it so I purged it. But some packages remained and `dunst` was the culprit!

I executed `sudo apt-get purge dunst` and then also `sudo apt-get purge i3 i3-wm i3lock suckless-tools i3status`.

Comment: I wonder why `purge` command does not actually purge ALL packages?