# After installing i3 I now have the i3 notification theme on unity. How can I change it back?

Tags: unity, configuration

I installed i3 alongside unity but now I see the i3 notification box while on unity.

[image]

How can I change this back to the unity one without removing i3? The other solutions to this problem seem to be removing the other WM/DE

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/a/383930/248158 It suggests getting rid of `dunst`.

Comment: `Package 'dunst' is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: It definitely looks like *dunst*.  What are the outputs of `type dunst` and `dpkg -S $(type -p dunst)`? This is also not really an issue  with *i3*: While the *i3* package (at least the official one) recommends the *dunst* package, *i3* has nothing to do with the *dunst* configuration. So the problem will not go away, just by removing *i3*.

Comment: They both showed it not installed.  I logged out and in and the unity style notification was back. I was messing with apt before clearing out old kernels so maybe it got removed with that somehow

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

run the following commands with`sudo`

create a file `/usr/bin/user_notify` and write
the following text to the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
if pgrep -x i3 >/dev/null ; then
  /usr/bin/dunst
else
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
fi
```

make the file executable by running `chmod a+x /usr/bin/user_notify`

open the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.knopwob.dunst.service`
and replace `Exec=/usr/bin/dunst` by `Exec=/usr/bin/user_notify`

**Remark** To use the standard unity notifier (also in i3) just
replace `Exec=/usr/bin/dunst` by `Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd`
in the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.knopwob.dunst.service`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, inspired by the other answers, `sudo apt remove dunst` and logging out and in again was sufficient.